# Firebase dynamic link keeps opening Play store

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a dynamic link `https://abc.test.link/test` on firebase.

and added following in `SplashActivity` intent filter.

```
  <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:host="abc.test.link"
            android:scheme="https"
            android:path="/test " />
    </intent-filter>
```

I am opening the URL from browser, and it launches the play store in my device, either app is installed or not.

If i download the app from `playstore` then it works fine, and launches the app, if its installed in the device.

But i want to test the scenario in debug apk. Is there any way to launch debug installed apk from firebase dynamic link.

Comment: Did you check the doc for dynamic links? https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/test

Comment: Also try adding ?d=1 at the end of the link to get a debug flowchart that can help with seeing issues. One guess would be missing a SHA256 being added to the console, but hard to tell without a link to check.